# Sass compilation fails when working directory is deeply nested and includePaths is relative

Tags: gulp-sass, libsass, node-sass

When attempting to import the scss of an npm package using `gulp-sass/node-sass/libsass`, it fails on

```
../../app/assets/stylesheets/_engine.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-material-design/scss/core
       Parent style sheet: /Users/kross/projects/acme/app/assets/stylesheets/_engine.scss
        on line 6 of ../../app/assets/stylesheets/_engine.scss
>> @import "bootstrap-material-design/scss/core";
   ^
```

Versions:

```
node-sass@3.4.2
gulp-sass@2.2.0
```

[While investigating this issue](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/issues/874), I've narrowed down potential external issues. It doesn't matter which file is substituted in this location, or it's contents (even empty contents), `libsass` seems to be unable to find the nested @import ***relative*** to the path of the ***found*** file.

In this case:

1. `includePaths: ['../../node_modules']`
2. Compilation command `cd spec/dummy && gulp sass` targets `application.scss`
3. Structure

**Note**: it is clear that `core` is found within the `bootstrap-material-design` package inside `node_modules`

[image: dir-structure]

It is clear that the nested file `_core.scss` is found, but that the nested file cannot find a file relative to it.

Also note, that if my `cwd` is at the root of this project, I _can_compile.  Moving the `cwd` down into `spec/dummy` and compiling, suddenly this nested relative file is no longer found.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched the `includePaths` relative path to a fully qualified path and it works.  [This appears to be a bug.](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1377#issuecomment-182635784)

The workaround is to ensure that any passed-in `includePaths` are fully qualified directory names.

[This gulp-pipeline recipe](https://github.com/alienfast/gulp-pipeline/blob/master/src/sass.js#L33) uses `findup` to do this:

```
  options: {
    includePaths: [findup('node_modules')] // find any node_modules above the current working directory and return the fully qualified path
  }
```